# How to convert large text pasted from clipboard into a single string?

Tags: python, ide

I want to copy HTTP request's headers from Chrome to either of my Python editors (I am using Geany and Spider).

In the editor, I want to treat the pasted text as a single string, so I am putting `'` around it like this:

```
'Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:CONSENT=YES+CH.de+V8; OGPC=19005936-2:19006965-1:19007018-1:; NID=134=DFX2Tsq7MTc9I99-OddiI1DXBW6KXfRgekXqACfJ62eFx6NlrwId4zoqrnZRqgO2GSrAgCtHM8Zt4v7rc56m6uNFhpDQZw2XOOM-6bEue2Kc9fA2POhFl6OdmnMattj8tadWOkd0IEH7KlYg1DRLURSQAqth-zVuVAxgzG9BuUna05kmjAhgcALy18_Mox7gyrhsOeiZ5ridT86ztpXMtA; DV=Qxe7uN9gVY0RECjFbPp1FKB3_LLEShY; 1P_JAR=2018-7-18-7
Host:www.google.ch
Referer:https://www.google.ch/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data:CJG2yQEIorbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIqKPKAQ=='
```

This however results in `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` on the first line.

Is this because of spaces or newline characters?

It works if I manually put everything into one line, but is there any way to avoid this manual work?

Comment: Use triple quotes for multi-line strings instead of a single quote (e.g. 

`'''my multiline string
lorem ipsum
'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of spaces or newline characters?

Yes, using single `'` or double `"` quotes in python doesn't let you write a string longer than one line. If you want to write a multiline string, use triple-quotes:

```
'''Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
...'''
```

---

Alternatively you can use string concatenation methods. But then you'll have to write the linebreaks explicitly (which makes this method inferior if you plan to copy-paste):

```
request = (
    'Accept:*/*\n'
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br\n'
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9\n'
    'Connection:keep-alive\n'
    ...
)
```